# Microsoft Graph API - What is the lifecycle of the SkipToken?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

To utilize paging of the Microsoft Graph API results, you can utilize the "skiptoken".

Does anyone know what the expiration date is on the skip token, if it's extendable, and if it's refreshable?

Comment: I don't believe this is published anywhere, but I'm curious: are you considering keeping a skip token around for anything longer than a few minutes?

Comment: If you want to retrieve the skip token, you could refer to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15a0d7ac-1489-4985-bcce-a04460398334/graph-api-skiptoken?forum=WindowsAzureAD).

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know what the expiration date is on the skip token, if it's extendable, and if it's refreshable?

I don't think that you need to care the lifecycle of the skiptoken.

Based on my understanding, it is the **equivalent of a cursor or bookmark**, that instructs the server where to resume the record. If you want to retrieve the rest record, the auth bearer token(access token) still required.

For more information about skiptoken parameter, please refer to this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#skiptoken-parameter).

Comment: This is generally correct. Technically the token is handled by the underlying service/workload so there can be differences in how they're generated/processed (i.e. OneDrive uses a different mechanism than AAD or Exchange). That said, you are correct, there isn't a specified TTL.